# Button not linking to another page?

Tags: html

This is my code, when I take away the span tag it works, did i do something illegal?

```
<center><button class="btn" href="about.html"><span>About</span></button></center>
```

Comment: The button element doesn't trigger navigation. Use the anchor element (`<a>`). Also, spend some time reading an HTML reference, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Comment: "when I take away the span tag it works" — It shouldn't do.

Comment: "did i do something illegal" — Yes, use a validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: 1999 called on a nokia. They want `<center>` back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using anchor tags

`<a href="about.html"><button class="btn"><span>About</span></button></a>`